# How do I fix "KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 1000'" when running ansible-playbook from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible

I have this jenkins pipeline that I use to execute `ansible-playbook`.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'gableroux/ansible'
            args '-i --entrypoint='
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Setup parameters') {
            steps {
                script {
                    properties([
                        parameters([
                            string( defaultValue: 'hosts', name: 'INVENTORY', trim: true ),
                            string( defaultValue: '\'*\'', name: 'LIMIT', trim: true ),
                            string( defaultValue: 'shell', name: 'PLAYBOOK', trim: true ),
                            string( defaultValue: '--list-hosts', name: 'EXTRA_PARAMS', trim: true )
                        ])
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Execute Ansible Playbook.') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP = env.WORKSPACE_TMP
                    env.HOME = env.WORKSPACE

                    sh """
                    ansible-playbook -i ${INVENTORY} -l "${LIMIT}" ${PLAYBOOK} ${EXTRA_PARAMS}
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I pass it these parameters:

```
INVENTORY -> ",localhost"
LIMIT -> ' '
PLAYBOOK -> 'the_playbook.yml'
EXTRA_PARAMS -> -vvv --connection=local --user root
```

The contents of `the_playbook.yml` are:

```
---
  - name: "Playing with Ansible and Git"
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    tasks:

    - name: "just execute a ls -lrt command"
      shell: "ls -lrt"
      register: "output"

    - debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

When my pipeline runs I get this error message:

```
+ ansible-playbook -i ,localhost -l ' ' the_playbook.yml -vvv '--connection=local' --user root
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Ansible will require Python 3.8 or newer on the 
controller starting with Ansible 2.12. Current version: 3.7.12 (default, Sep  8
 2021, 01:55:52) [GCC 10.3.1 20210424]. This feature will be removed from 
ansible-core in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ansible-playbook [core 2.11.5] 
  config file = /var/jenkins_home/workspace/run_ansibleplaybook/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/var/jenkins_home/workspace/run_ansibleplaybook/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /var/jenkins_home/workspace/run_ansibleplaybook/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.7.12 (default, Sep  8 2021, 01:55:52) [GCC 10.3.1 20210424]
  jinja version = 3.0.1
  libyaml = False
Using /var/jenkins_home/workspace/run_ansibleplaybook/ansible.cfg as config file
Parsed ,localhost inventory source with host_list plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: the_playbook.yml *****************************************************
1 plays in the_playbook.yml

PLAY [Playing with Ansible and Git] ********************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
task path: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/run_ansibleplaybook/the_playbook.yml:2
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 158, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 532, in _execute
    self._connection = self._get_connection(cvars, templar)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 874, in _get_connection
    ansible_playbook_pid=to_text(os.getppid())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/loader.py", line 837, in get_with_context
    obj.__init__(instance, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/local.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.default_user = getpass.getuser()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/getpass.py", line 169, in getuser
    return pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 1000'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Try using the Ansible plugin for Jenkins Pipeline if it is possible. It would be much easier. Besides that, I feel fairly certain you need to fix this with the `become` meta-parameter as an argument (not necessarily to a user with elevated permissions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
sh '''
echo "tempuser:x:$(id -u):$(id -g):,,,:${HOME}:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd
echo "tempuser:x:$(id -G | cut -d' ' -f 2)" >> /etc/group
'''
sh """
ansible-playbook -i ${INVENTORY} -l "${LIMIT}" ${PLAYBOOK} ${EXTRA_PARAMS}
"""
```

Or you can try creating a user with UID 1000 in the base image. Refer [this](https://major.io/2019/03/22/running-ansible-in-openshift-with-arbitrary-uids/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I got this error: [Pipeline] sh
+ id -u
+ id -g
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/run_ansibleplaybook@tmp/durable-ddb0d054/script.sh: line 2: can't create /etc/passwd: Permission denied

Comment: Is there a way to add the user when running docker run? Something like `docker run --user=1000 ... ` or something?

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way. Jenkins starts the container with an arbitrary user for security reasons. Another option would be to add that user to the Host machine and mount /etc/passwd into the container.